# How to preserve formating of lambda expression in Resharper?

Tags: c#, formatting, resharper

When Resharper applies formating style for this code

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
});
```

the result (not expected) looks like this:

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(c => { c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" }); });
```

My current settings for "Line Breaks and Wrapping" in Resharper:

[image: Line Breaks and Wrapping]

**Question:**
Is there a combination of settings to preserve the original formatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn on a setting named "Keep existing arrangement of embedded blocks". To discover settings affecting your piece of code you can use "Configure formatting" feature. Select a code in question, Alt-Enter > Format selection > Configure...
[image: Configure formatting screenshot]

Comment: Great, that is exactly what I was looking for!